# How can an angular "array/object" be properly deepcloned with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, clone

I have to clone an array with some objects inside.
I tried "JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)" and thirdParty Plugin Lodash, but both are return a empty result. Do i have the wrong data to clone ?

The Function looks so:

```
currentObject: any[];
addPropertiesToDisplay() {
console.log(this.analyseFacade.householdService.currentObject);
this.currentObject = _cloneDeep(this.analyseFacade.householdService.currentObject);
console.log(this.currentObject);
```

}

the console.log shows this

[image]

Comment: You may be missing the dot after your underscore. Try: this.currentObject = _.cloneDeep(this.analyseFacade.householdService.currentObject);

Comment: hmm i get an error if i try this. I think this was an older version import from lodash. 

I imported it like "import { cloneDeep as _cloneDeep } from 'lodash';"

and installed "lodash-es" and  "@types/lodash-es"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by writing a empty Object to the stringify. This should also work for Lodash. But in this case i dont use a third party plugin.

```
this.currentObject = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this.analyseFacade.householdService.currentObject))
);
```

Comment: This makes a shallow clone of `this.analyseFacade.householdService.currentObject`. See [MDN's warning about `Object.assign` doing a shallow clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone).

Comment: Yes u are right, i know this and i know i have to fix the Service where the data came from to clone it here in a correct way.